# Why is that line on canvas staying forever?

Tags: canvas

I am making a canvas painting app.

This is my text class:

```
const Text = class {
  constructor(ctx, colorPicker, text, coordinates) {
    this.ctx = ctx,
    this.colorPicker = colorPicker,
    this.text = text || "Text...",
    this.coordinates = coordinates,
    this.measure = this.ctx.measureText(this.text),
    this.underline = {
      x1: undefined,
    }

  }
  draw() {
    this.ctx.font = `normal 20px Lora`
    this.ctx.textBaseline = 'alphabetic'
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "red"
    this.ctx.textAlign = "left"
    this.ctx.textBaseline = "bottom"
    this.ctx.fillText(this.text, this.coordinates.x, this.coordinates.y )
    this.ctx.stroke()
  }
  update() {
    this.draw()
  }
  drawUnderline() {
    this.ctx.beginPath()
    this.ctx.moveTo(this.coordinates.x - this.measure.actualBoundingBoxLeft, this.coordinates.y)
    this.ctx.lineTo(this.coordinates.x + this.measure.actualBoundingBoxRight, this.coordinates.y)
    this.ctx.stroke()
  }
}

export default Text
```

This is my animation function:

```
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)

  if (texts[0]) {
    console.log("texts 0")
    texts.forEach(text => {
      text.update()
    })
  }

  if (currentText && isDrawingText) {
      console.log("is drawing text")
      drawText(ctx, colorPicker, textToPlace, { x: textCoordinates.x, y: textCoordinates.y })
      currentText.drawUnderline()
  }
}
```

This is what happens when I click on canvas:

```
const start = (event) => {

    isDrawingText = true
    textCoordinates.x = event.offsetX
    textCoordinates.y = event.offsetY

    drawText(ctx, colorPicker, textToPlace, { x: textCoordinates.x, y: textCoordinates.y })
  
}
```

This is my drawing function:

```
import Text from '../classes/Text.js'

let texts = []
let currentText = null

const drawText = (ctx, colorPicker, textToPlace, coordinates) => {

  let textCoordinates = {
    x: undefined,
    y: undefined
  }

  if (coordinates.x && coordinates.y) {
    textCoordinates.x = coordinates.x,
    textCoordinates.y = coordinates.y
  }

  currentText = new Text(ctx, colorPicker.value, textToPlace, textCoordinates)
  
  currentText.update(true)
}

export { texts, drawText, currentText }
```

And this is what happens when I hit enter:

```
if (e.key === 'Enter') {
  texts.push(currentText)
  isDrawingText = false
} else if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
  textToPlace = textToPlace.substring(0, textToPlace.length - 1)
} else if (e.key !== 'Shift' && e.location === 0) {
  textToPlace = textToPlace + e.key
}
```

An the last part is where it is getting weird. I would expect animation function to stop drawing current shape and start drawing shapes from shapes array when I hit Enter. And it seems like this is happening (based on console.logs).
BUT the underline stays on canvas, it only get's a little lighter. This seems not to make much sense as it should only be drawn when the current text is drawn, and the current text is not drawn any more (isDrawingText varialble is set to false), so where does it come from? Can anybody please help me understand what's happening here??

Comment: At the end of `draw` you have a lone `stroke()` that will paint the current path of the context. This current path is the underline. This is also why it's darker when you also draw the text, it's stroked twice. You may want to prefer Path2D objects these days.

Comment: with that comment you not only helped me with the above issue, but also with the new one I had today. this is an answer, actually. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but more than a comment.

I have finally got rid of the line by refactoring my Text class drawUnderline
method into:

```
drawUnderline() {
    this.ctx.lineTo(this.coordinates.x + this.measure.actualBoundingBoxRight, this.coordinates.y)
    this.ctx.stroke()
    this.ctx.beginPath()
    this.ctx.moveTo(this.coordinates.x - this.measure.actualBoundingBoxLeft, this.coordinates.y)
 }
```

But It was just a random try. I don't understand why did I have to do it. If you know the answer, I still need it, please.